# MongoDB $push in Array of Array Error: No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'elements'

Tags: database, mongodb, typescript, mongodb-query, push

I wish to add data into Elements but get error. How to solve this mongodb/typescript problem?

Attempt 1 Error: No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'elements'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.ts(18004)

Attempt 1

```
  async add<T extends { id: string; parentID: string, elementNum: number, name: string, link: string}>(collectionName: string, args: T) {
    const db = await this.getDB();
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        collection.updateOne({ id: args.id }, {$push: {elements[args.elementNum]: {id: uuid(), name: args.name, link: args.link, elements: [] }}}, (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve(res);
        });
    });
  }
```

Attempt 2
changed the following

```
    collection.updateOne({ id: args.id }, {$push: {elements: {id: uuid(), name: args.name, link: args.link, elements: [] }}},
```

Attempt 2 results in Null added in the end

```
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "wk1",
            "iconFile": "icon.png",
            "elements": [
                [
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "element2",
                        "link": "https",
                        "elements": [
                            {
                                "id": "1",
                                "name": "element1",
                                "link": "https:"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "name": "element3",
                        "link": "https://",
                        "elements": [
                            {
                                "id": "4",
                                "name": "w",
                                "link": "http:/"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "name": "element3",
                        "link": "https://",
                        "elements": [
                            {
                                "id": "4",
                                "name": "w",
                                "link": "http://"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "name": "element3",
                        "link": "https://",
                        "elements": [
                            {
                                "id": "4",
                                "name": "w",
                                "link": "http://www."
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                null,
            ]
        }
```

What I want to achieve is the following

```
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "wk1",
            "iconFile": "icon.png",
            "elements": [
                [
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "element2",
                        "link": "https",
                        "elements": [
                            {
                                "id": "1",
                                "name": "element1",
                                "link": "https:"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                                "id": "newid",
                                "name": "newname",
                                "link": "newlink"
                                "elements":[]
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "name": "element3",
                        "link": "https://",
                        "elements": [
                            .......
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dnmg3lL2891

Use - [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

> The all positional operator $[] indicates that the update operator
> should modify all elements in the specified array field.
>
> The $[] operator has the following form:
>
> `{ <update operator>: { "<array>.$[]" : value } }`

```
db.collection.update({ _id: 1, "add.id": "1"},
{ $push: { "add.$[].elements": { id: "3", name: "a",  link: "" } } })
```

---

Demo to push array instead of object - https://mongoplayground.net/p/dh3NSutIv4-

```
db.collection.update({ _id: 1, "add.id": "1"},
{ $push: { "add.$[].elements": [{ id: "3", name: "a",  link: "" }] } })
```

---

```js
const args = {};
args.elementNum = 0;

const update = {
  [`add.$[].elements.${args.elementNum}`]: {
    a: 1
  }
};

console.log(update);

//collection.updateOne({ id: args.id }, update); // use like this
```

Comment: Can you check the edit. I want to push to existing array.

Comment: @javascriptnoob I didn't get your point, please check the demo, we are pushing inside `add.elements`. That's what you need right ?

Comment: I do not want to create another array like in demo. Array amount should always be 3 and I want to insert data into existing array either 0, 1, 2 specified by args.elementNum

Comment: @javascriptnoob Check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/FKdPBY9FrFg you can speicify `add.$[].elements.0`. Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: @curiostushar yes, but cannot pass in args.elementNum into string. "add.$[].elements.$args.elementNum"

Comment: @javascriptnoob you can pass `"add.$[].elements." + args.elementNum` in JS which will result in `add.$[].elements.0` ?

Comment: Or using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals `add.$[].elements.${args.elementNum}`

Comment: that results in error: ':' expected.ts(1005) for me

Comment: Can show the exact code what did you try ?